# How to switch arch linux to lts kernel?

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, grub, lts

I'm running a headless server installation of arch linux. The high rate of kernel upgrades caused me some maintainance headache and I therefore wish to switch to the [lts kernel](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=linux-lts).

I already installed the `linux-lts` and `linux-lts-headers` packages. Now, I got both kernels installed but I'm a bit clueless how to continue from here. The [docs explain](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Install_the_linux-lts_package):

> [...] you will need to update your bootloader's configuration file to use the LTS kernel and ram disk: `vmlinuz-linux-lts` and `initramfs-linux-lts.img`.

I already located them in the boot section:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ ll /boot/
total 85M
4,0K drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4,0K 21. Mai 13:46 ./
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 15:08 ../
4,0K drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 14:50 grub/
 27M -rw-r--r--  1 root root  27M 20. Mai 17:01 initramfs-linux-fallback.img
 12M -rw-r--r--  1 root root  12M 20. Mai 17:01 initramfs-linux.img
 27M -rw-r--r--  1 root root  27M 21. Mai 13:46 initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
 12M -rw-r--r--  1 root root  12M 21. Mai 13:46 initramfs-linux-lts.img
 16K drwx------  2 root root  16K  4. Apr 14:47 lost+found/
4,3M -rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,3M 11. Mai 22:23 vmlinuz-linux
4,2M -rw-r--r--  1 root root 4,2M 19. Mai 21:05 vmlinuz-linux-lts
```

Now, I already found entries pointing to the non-lts kernel in the `grub.cfg` but the header tells me not to edit this file. It points me to the utility `grub-mkconfig` instead but I can not figure out how to use this tool to tell grub which kernel and ramdisk to use.

How to switch archlinux with grub to the lts kernel? What else do I have to be cautious about when switching the kernel?

Comment: [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Invoking-grub_002dmkconfig.html) is the simplest invocation. the tool should autolocate your existing kernels (plus extra bits like ramdisk, microcode etc) and automatically add them. [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration) gives a nice overview of how you can configure the resulting `grub.cfg` file.

Comment: also, you can add entries to files in `/etc/grub.d` - see [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/manually-addingremoving-entries-to-grub-2-menu)

Comment: Run grub-mkconfig, check that you see a stanza for linux-lts in grub.cfg, and reboot.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Okay, after joe pointed me the right direction in comments, this is how I did it:

1. basicly just install `pacman -S linux-lts`
2. (optional) check if kernel, ramdisk and fallback are available in `ls -lsha /boot`
3. remove the standard kernel `pacman -R linux`
4. update the grub config `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
5. reboot

Note, for `syslinux` you'll need to edit the syslinux config file in `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` accordingly, just point everything to the `-lts` kernel.

Comment: Note that one may need to replace any kernel modules with their lts equivalent as well. e.g. if `acpi_call` was previously installed, it's probably best to also install `acpi_call-lts`, otherwise the module won't load.

Comment: FWIW you can skip step 3 and have both kernels installed at once. For me, `lts` was selected by default after rebooting, but I could also go into grub's `advanced options` and select the standard kernel instead.

Comment: Mine got stuck at boot of initramfs and I had to manually run `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux-lts`.

Comment: and how do I switch back?

Comment: step 4 is critical, otherwise you have to manually edit grub at boot time in order to boot the correct kernel.

Comment: I also needed to uninstall `nvidia` and install `nvidia-lts` since `linux` is a dependency of `nvidia`

Answer (score 9):

[The answer from Afri](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284627/118138) works well for GRUB, but I’m [using UEFI directly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB#Using_UEFI_directly), which is more lightweight and makes full use of the UEFI motherboard.

1. Install `linux-lts`
2. (optional) Check if LTS version of kernel, ramdisk and fallback are available in `/boot` folder.
3. Generate the EFI entry, the same way as you generated the regular Linux one, but replacing ramdisk and loader with the LTS ones. For example:

   ```
   efibootmgr --disk /dev/sdX --part Y --create --label "Arch Linux LTS" --loader /vmlinuz-linux-lts --unicode 'root=PARTUUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX rw initrd=\initramfs-linux-lts.img' --verbose
   ```

   Note the `--loader` value and `initrd` value. These files should be in the `/boot` folder.
4. Reboot. You may want to adjust the boot order in motherboad before booting into the operating system, for example by pressing F12 (depending on your motherboard). I actually use Hyper-V, which allows boot order configuration in "Hyper-V Manager".
5. (optional) After successfully booting into the LTS kernel (verify it with `uname -r`), remove the standard kernel with `pacman -R linux`.

Answer (score 7):

1. Install `linux-lts` (or any other kernel):

   ```
   pacman -S linux-lts
   ```
2. Update your boot loader entry:

   ```
   $ sudo vim /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf
   ```

   and change:

   ```
   linux   /vmlinuz-linux
   initrd  /initramfs-linux.img
   ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
   linux   /vmlinuz-linux-lts
   initrd  /initramfs-linux-lts.img
   ```
3. Reboot and confirm with `uname -r`

Comment: adding separate entry is an option ;) Keeping the latest and greatest one untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Like Franklin Yu, I'm also on a system without GRUB. I needed to switch to a different kernel and haven't used efibootmgr before. I asked a more knowledgeable friend about this and **he suggested the tool [rEFInd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/REFInd)**, which automates the steps that Franklin suggested and presents you with a nice menu at boot time of which kernels you have available. The installation was totally straightforward and I was able to switch kernel versions easily.

Comment: In my machine (Arch Linux dual boot with Windows + rEFInd), after installing the `lts` kernel, I also need to edit `refind_linux.conf`: change `initrd=/boot/initramfs-linux.img` to `initrd=/boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img`.

Comment: refind supports arch without extra edits @dmn. i am doing below to install, especially the "extra_kernel_version_strings" is important. sorry for the extra post below, did not get it to format correctly in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [this answer, daniel shapero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581155/364985). [refind](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/REFInd) supports Arch without extra edits @dmn. I am doing the below to install `refind`, especially the "extra_kernel_version_strings" is important, the EFI directory is yours, does dual boot Windows as well automatically in case you have Windows on it, or other Linux distros:

```
pacman -S refind
mkdir -p /efi/EFI/Boot
cp /usr/share/refind/refind_x64.efi /efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp -r /usr/share/refind/drivers_x64/ /efi/EFI/Boot/
echo 'extra_kernel_version_strings linux,linux-hardened,linux-lts,linux-zen,linux-git;' > /efi/EFI/Boot/refind.conf
echo 'fold_linux_kernels false' >> /efi/EFI/Boot/refind.conf
echo 'default_selection "linux from"' >> /efi/EFI/Boot/refind.conf
```