# Run Arch with LTS Kernel alongside. No UI

Tags: arch-linux, kernel

I have a fresh Arch installation, running the latest kernel. I'm using systemd-boot, Xorg, GDM and Gnome.

Everything runs smoothly so far. The only issue I have is with my Decklink Card. The driver for it only works until Kernel 4.14. (see [this](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/decklink/))

To resolve this, I would like to have the LTS-Kernel installed alongside and be able to choose on bootup via the systemd-boot menu, which kernel to load.

Following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284617/how-to-switch-arch-linux-to-lts-kernel), I installed the LTS-Kernel (but didn't remove the current one)
I duplicated the original boot-entry and changed the "linux" and "initrd" parameters to point to `/vmlinuz-linux-lts` and `initramfs-linux-lts` respectively.

**So far so good, but here (finally) comes the issue:** - The system starts with both Kernels, but the LTS-Version doesn't launch the Graphical Interface. (It still works when I start it with the latest Kernel)

On tty1  all the green [  OK  ] run through but then the system just stops with a blinking cursor. But I cannot type anything. (I can login on another tty, no problem there)

To clarify it does output the following:

```
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target Graphical Interface.
```

What am I missing here? What prevents the UI from showing up, since all seems... [  OK  ] ?

Comment: Are both kernel command lines identical? Check with cat /proc/cmdline

Comment: Except for one pointing to initramfs-linux-lts.img, they are identical. (Copy-pasted the boot entry and inserted "-lts")

Comment: Does this help? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234087

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have actually come across the linked thread and tried the solution before posting my question. No success there.

Comment: Doing further testing, I believe, this is an issue with Xorg's configuration. When I try to start it manually, I get weird flickering. I had the same, when I messed up the xorg.conf while running the latest Kernel. So I couldn't get any UI at all. But I also found out that Blackmagicdesign have updated their driver! So, long story short, I rebuilt the whole thing. No workaround needed. Everything is running smootly. :)  Still interested in why this wouldn't work, in case this comes up again.