# Changed to linux-lts and removed linux, now I cannot boot

Tags: arch-linux, grub, uefi

I followed [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284627/441221) to install the lts kernel, but the last command `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` did not go through and now I cannot boot into Arch. I have a usb stick with Arch on it and I think I need to change the config in `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` but I don't know how. Also I have installed Arch in a LVM.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you using [GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB) or [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-boot)?

Comment: it uses uefi, so I think it is systemd-boot. How can I verify this? I followed this guide https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Installation_mit_UEFI_und_Verschl%C3%BCsselung#UEFI-Bootloader_installieren_und_konfigurieren it says systemd for uefi

Comment: GRUB can be used with [UEFI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) too but if you just followed the guide you are probably using `systemd-boot`. (How to verify this would be a topic on its own. If you did not install `grub` and the command `grub-mkconfig` did not go through because the command was missing you most definitely are not using GRUB as boot loader.)

Answer (score 0):

> Note, for `syslinux` you'll need to edit the syslinux config file in `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` accordingly, just point everything to the `-lts` kernel.

It seems you are using [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot) as [bootloader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_boot_process#Boot_loader). [syslinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Syslinux) would be another alternative but you could have inferred (from the [other answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564478/270414) to that [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284617/how-to-switch-arch-linux-to-lts-kernel)) that this also applies to your situation if you are not using [GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB).

To fix your boot issue you should make the [appropriate modifications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564478/270414) in the entry `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` (i.e. append -lts to `linux /vmlinuz-linux` and insert -lts into `initrd /initramfs-linux.img`).

To access the file you can simply [mount](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/File_systems#Mount_a_file_system) the [EFI system partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition) from any live environment (i.e. the Arch Linux installation CD/USB).

Comment: I tried to mount /mnt earlier today, but it didn't work. I've setup the system last week and as I need it tomorrow, so I went with a fresh install.

but this looks like what I was looking for. Thanks nevertheless for your effort

Comment: I think the error was that there was no /mnt and I think this was due to the lvm, but I'm not sure. I should have to login before mounting, amirite?